# Is it possible to import the PHP's library file php_curl.dll in another language like VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, curl, dllimport

I would like to create a webpage data parser and for that needs, I would like it to run in a Dekstop application.

I would like to know if we can import `php_curl.dll` in a **VB.NET** applications ?

And if you guys have a little example.. :P I'll enjoy reading it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen System.Net.WebClient?  This should let you download html (and other content) from the web.

```
Dim html As String
Using wc As New WebClient()
   html = wc.DownloadString("http://stackoverflow.com")
End Using
```

Comment: Does the WebClient object supports common cURL features like no url length limit, cookies, SSL support? Also, I dont want the request to be cached.

Comment: WebClient does not cache, and supports most of those features (I'm not sure about cookies). If you need a feature it doesn't support, look at System.Net.HttWebRequest/HttpWebResponse, which allow you to compose raw http requests.

Comment: Thank you, wouldn't it be a little bit more effective (faster) to call a C++ library then using a .NET object in the Framework ?

Comment: No. The driving factor in performance for this is the actual download from the web.  C++ is limited to the same network connection as .Net.  Aside from that, you asked to import this into a .Net language eventually anyway.  Many of the .Net classes are implemented in unmanaged code where performance will matter.  Since you have to pay the performance penalty to load the .Net runtime, you may as well stay there.

Answer (score 0):

You have curl on windows so you dont need to take php curl [curl download page](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

Comment: Allright, I guess I could use the "original" library too. Which is probably more effective in a Desktop Application. What about the socket managements if I import it in a VB.NET application ? Does that library support sockets internally ?

Comment: have a look here please: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/vb/ i did not use curl with vb, but  read the tutorial and i hope will find what you need (atually i never programmed in vb :D)